# Excel: View Column A from Multiple Worksheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have many excel sheets with Categories

```
Car Worksheet1 - Column A has car parts (Engine, tire, windshield, etc),
Furniture Worksheet2 - Column has a furniture (Couch, lamp, table)
Kitchen Worksheet3 - Column A has kitchen parts (sink, microwave, refrigerator),
```

I want to create a Everything worksheet that contains All the worksheets Column A (without copying and pasting).
It would list everything in Worksheet sequentially: Engine, tire, windshield, couch, lamp, table, sink, microwave, refrigerator

How can I accomplish this? I didn't see the function in Data-> Consolidate

Prefer to use excel equations vs pivot table. However, if pivot table/query is the only option, I will use as answer then.

Comment: Try this formula `=VSTACK(Car:Kitchen!A:A)`

Comment: hi @MayukhBhattacharya not sure what you mean, I just edited description though, thanks

Comment: Edited the comment, since there was a typo earlier in your post. As you are trying to append the data from all the worksheets into one, from `Column A` you can use the above formula: `=VSTACK(Car:Kitchen!A2:A1000)` note that it works with `MS365`

Comment: **[look here](https://imgur.com/gallery/RNcYy81)**

Comment: hi @MayukhBhattacharya , if you want to write as answer, I can send points, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Assuming no Excel Constraints as per your tags. Then the following formula will work for your requirements.*

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `A2`

```
=TOCOL(
    VSTACK(
        Car:Kitchen!A2:A1000
    ),
    1
)
```

---

Or, just using `TOCOL()` as mentioned below by **[JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv)** Sir

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `A2`

```
=TOCOL(Car:Kitchen!A:A,1)
```

---

**Note:** `TOCOL()`, with parameter `1` ignores the blanks.

---

**[Workbook_with_Solution](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2cjCRaM1ZbICcmt5GQ?e=nCpfXS)**

---